# redirect deleted / drafted pages

Tags: 404-error, publish, draft

A client asked me to unpublished a page, which I did. However, I kept it as a draft, just in case they wanted to republish at a future date.

My issue is that anyone with this link will hit a 404 page, which I've read is generally a thing to avoid (Google apparently penalises you if you have too many?).

Is there a better way to handle this?